# Is there aught to help me dry faster?

Tags: dragons-dogma

I find myself oft getting soaked and losing the light from my lantern after exploring some stream. Usually when this happens I just walk around until I'm not wet anymore. Is there a faster way to dry off, or at least a faster way to get my lantern turned on again?

I'm currently fairly early the in game, exploring the Witchwood.

Comment: If you put away your lamp and then equip it again, it should light up even though you're still soaked. This might be a bug, so I'm not submitting it as an answer (besides, the currently accepted answer is certainly the "right" way)

Comment: @Tzarium: That was the first thing I tried, and it didn't work for me. (PS3, patched up as of yesterday.)

Comment: Darn, they probably patched it. I hadn't tried since launch :(

Comment: The put away / use trick still works (PS3), although it's a bit of a pain.  Also, +1 for using "aught" in the question.

Comment: I know most people probably don't realize just how in-depth this game truly is. Point one is that your height does in fact play a very large role in whether or not you walking in water will put out your lantern. First game I played my character was very tall. Except for when I literally waded out into a pool of water that was deeper than my knees, my lantern would not go out walking through streams. As a counter example, on my new game+, I changed my character to a very short dwarvish looking girl. I could not walk into any body of water without my lantern going out.

Comment: I'm also fairly certain that your character creation effects quite a few other things as well. Like how fast you run, how high/far you jump, stuff like that, though as I haven't played DD in a while, I can't really confirm this at the moment and these are things I remember.(As my memory is hardly infallible, I won't put forth the idea than any of the things I said are 100% true, but they are definitely testable by anyone that wants to find out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an item called "Clean Cloth" which you can buy or find in gather spots, particularly in textile shops.
I only know of two locations so far though, one in the starting town in an abandoned cloth workers shop, and one in Madeleine's shop the capital.
Both have gather spots in the cloth racks.

Comment: Absorbent cloths, which I've found are a little more common, can be turned into clean cloths by combining with a flask of water, but frankly, unless nearby enemies are using lightning or ice attacks, there's little reason not to just continue on and let the drenched effect wear off.